# what if i keep my class members are public?

Tags: c++, python

In c++ instance variables are private by default,in Python variables are public by default

i have two questions regarding the same:-

1: why Python have all the members are public by default?

2: People say you should  your member data should be private
   what if i make my data to be public?
   what are the disadvantages of this approch?
   why it is a bad design?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use a leading underscore in the name to tell readers of the code that the name in question is an internal detail and they must not rely on it remaining in future versions.  Such a convention is really all you need -- why weigh the language down with an enforcement mechanism?

Data, just like methods, should be public (named without a leading underscore) if they're part of your class's designed API which you intend to support going forward.  In C++, or Java, that's unlikely to happen because if you want to change the data member into an accessor method, you're out of luck -- you'll have to break your API and every single client of the class will have to change.

In Python, and other languages supporting a `property`-like construct, that's not the case -- you can always replace a data member with a property which calls accessor methods transparently, the API does not change, nor does client code.  So, in Python and other languages with `property`-like constructs (I believe .NET languages are like that, at source-code level though not necessarily at bytecode level), you may as well leave your data public when it's part of the API and no accessors are currently needed (you can always add accessor methods to later implementation releases if need be, and not break the API).

So it's not really a general OO issue, it's language specific: does a given language support a property-like construct.  Python does.

Comment: +1.. love the answer..specially where you said "why weigh the language down with an enforcement mechanism?"

Comment: The comment about .NET languages is false. Changing from a field to a property is an API-breaking change.

Comment: @Porges, it breaks _binary_ compatibility, but not _programming_ compatibility: client programs are unchanged, they just need to be recompiled.

Comment: @Alex, changing from a field to a property or vise versa can lead to runtime failures. Old databinding methods in particular only supported binding to properties, not fields. In particular, anyone working with your types using reflection could possibly break from such a change and only discover it at runtime.

Comment: @Alex, that's true for C#, but other languages (may) have differing support for properties.

Comment: You can actually implement "properties" in C++ with some (one-off) template magic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/820569/is-there-a-perl-script-to-implement-c-class-get-set-member-functions/820861#820861.  There are some cosmetic differences, e.g. you must use function-call syntax, but the convenience is there and this approach does allow for replacement of reads and writes with separate functions later on at the cost of recompilation.

Answer (score 3):

I can't comment on Python, but in C++, structs provide public access by default.

The primary reason you want a private part of your class is that, without one, it is impossible to guarantee your invariants are satisfied.  If you have a string class, for instance, that is supposed to keep track of the length of the string, you need to be able to track insertions. But if the underlying `char*` member is public, you can't do that.  Anybody can just come along and tack something onto the end, or overwrite your null terminator, or call `delete[]` on it, or whatever.  When you call your `length()` member, you just have to hope for the best.

Answer (score 1):

It's really a question of language design philosophies. I favour the Python camp so might come down a little heavy handedly on the C++ style but the bottom line is that in C++ it's possible to forcibly prevent users of your class from accessing certain internal parts.

In Python, it's a matter of convention and stating that it's internal. Some applications might want to access the internal member for non-malignant purposes (eg. documentation generators). Some users who know what they're doing might want to do the same. People who want to shoot themselves in the foot twiddling with the internal details are not protected from suicide.

Like Dennis said "Anybody can just come along and tack something onto the end, or overwrite your null terminator". Python treats the user like an adult and expects her to take care of herself.  C++ protects the user as one would a child.

Comment: But still, the thing that saves the day in Python is properties. Without any support from the language, it would otherwise be a lot of work to change the user code, should things get critical / a need arise to do something when a field is modified.

Answer (score 0):

[This is why](http://www.archive.org/details/SeanKellyRecoveryfromAddiction).